# How to invert scale display on radar chart (chart.js)

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

hello does anyone has any idea on how to invert the scale display on my graph? i want it to start from 100, ending with 0

i tried with scale:reverse but it didnt work

```
var scaling = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
var barData = {
  labels: [["PH"],
      ["Heavy Metals"],
      ["Chemical Oxygen Demand"],
      ["Transparency"],
      "Ammonia Nitrogen",
      ["Dissolved", "Oxygen"],],
  datasets: [
    {
      fillColor: "#48A497",
      strokeColor: "#48A4D1",
      data: [2, 10, 7, 10, 7, 10].map(function (e, i) {
        return e * scaling[i];
      }),
    },
  ],
};

var income = document.getElementById("income").getContext("2d");
new Chart(income).Radar(barData, {
  tooltipTemplate: function (valueObject) {
    return (
      valueObject.value / scaling[data.labels.indexOf(valueObject.label)]
    );
  },
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyqiE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works,

```
var scaling = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
[2, 10, 7, 10, 7, 10].map(function (e, i) {
    return scaling[i] = e * scaling[i];
})

var barData = {
    labels: [
        ["PH"],
        ["Heavy Metals"],
        ["Chemical Oxygen Demand"],
        ["Transparency"],
        "Ammonia Nitrogen",
        ["Dissolved", "Oxygen"],
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "#48A497",
            strokeColor: "#48A4D1",
            data: scaling.sort(function(a, b) {
                return b-a;
            }),
        },
    ],
};

var income = document.getElementById("income").getContext("2d");
new Chart(income).Radar(barData, {
    tooltipTemplate: function (valueObject) {
        return (
            valueObject.value / scaling[data.labels.indexOf(valueObject.label)]
        );
    },
});
```